# What is the value of this gaussian-like integral?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

What is the value of this integral ?

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} \int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} \exp \left( -\frac{A}{2}(x-y)^2 + B (x-y) \right) dx dy
\end{equation}

Note that $A,B$ are Real and positive. I can expand it as
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} dx \exp(-A/2x^2+ Bx) \int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} dy \exp \left( -\frac{A}{2}y^2 + y(Ax - B) \right)
\end{equation}
Doing the Gaussian integral in $y$ gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{\sqrt{iA}} \int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} dx \exp \left(-A/2x^2+Bx + (Ax -  B)^2/2A \right) dx 
\end{equation}
Cancelling terms in exponent gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{\sqrt{A}}  \exp \left(+B^2/2A \right) \int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} dx  
\end{equation}
Basically the area under the line in the $y$ direction is (excluding constant factors) the inverse of its probability density in the $x$ direction. Summed over $x$ it becomes infinite.

Postscript: I later determined that the integral over $y$ (which enforces a lagrange multiplier constraint) was not required as the system is underdetermined. So the infinity went away. :-)

Comment: If you claim it is nonconvergent, then would that not be the "value" you claim? If you doubt that, why not just [edit] your claimed solution into your post, so people can critique it? As is, it makes it come off as you expecting us to do all the leg-work, which is not kosher for this site.

Comment: Yes. I guess so. I might add my workings. I thought someone might recognise it.

Comment: @PrincessEev - I added my workings. If the downvote was yours maybe you can zero it.

Answer (score 4):

Try a simple change of variables: $u=x-y$, $v=x+y$. You will end up with a one dimensional Gaussian integral in $u$, and an integral over the entire domain for $dv$. The first one is finite and positive, the second is infinite. When you multiply the two you will get $+\infty$.

Comment: This is what I find. It surprised me as I thought it would be finite.

Comment: The way it looks is like an infinite ridge in the $x+y$ direction, with a cross section that is a Gaussian in the $x-y$ direction.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Thanks.